# #1054 - Unknown column using left join

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i'm struggling to get this SQL query to work.
I'm attempting to grab the information I need in one query because the data I get will be converted to CSV using PHP.

The following SQL query I have is:

```
SELECT C.customer_ID, C.l_Name AS Surname, 
C.f_Name AS 'First Name', C.travel_Date,
T.tour_Name, 
S.f_Name AS Staff, S.l_Name AS Staff_Surname, 
PA.pay_Method 
FROM Customers AS C 
LEFT JOIN Tour AS T ON C.trip_Taken = T.tour_ID 
LEFT JOIN Staff AS S ON O.staff_ID = S.staff_ID 
LEFT JOIN Payment AS PA ON O.pay_ID = PA.pay_ID 
WHERE C.customer_ID NOT IN (SELECT O.customer_ID 
FROM Customers AS C, Orders AS O 
WHERE C.travel_Date >= '2014-07-08 00:00:00' 
AND C.travel_Date <= '2014-07-08 23:59:59' AND C.customer_ID = O.customer_ID )
```

I'm getting this error `#1054 - Unknown column 'O.staff_ID' in 'on clause'` and I'm not sure how to go about fixing it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Running MySQL 5.0 and latest PHP

Comment: The `O` is introduced in the sub-query, this is not accessible during the JOIN. (I would remove the IN .. SELECT entirely and replace it with a[nother] JOIN.)

Comment: @user2864740 How do you propose I go about writing this? SQL isn't my strong suite here lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the reason of the error from other answer. If you really want to join with `Orders` then include another `JOIN` clause with `Orders` like below

```
FROM Customers AS C 
LEFT JOIN Tour AS T ON C.trip_Taken = T.tour_ID
LEFT JOIN Orders AS OO ON C.customer_ID = OO.customer_ID <--Included
LEFT JOIN Staff AS S ON OO.staff_ID = S.staff_ID <-- Join with Orders
LEFT JOIN Payment AS PA ON OO.pay_ID = PA.pay_ID
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This lead me on the right path to get the correct query. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

At some point you wrote

```
LEFT JOIN Staff AS S ON O.staff_ID = S.staff_ID
```

but "O" is defined inside parenthesis scope. Change your query in

```
LEFT JOIN Staff AS S ON Orders.staff_ID = S.staff_ID
```

Comment: I tried that and I end up getting this #1054 - Unknown column 'Orders.staff_ID' in 'on clause' Yes the Orders table and column "staff_ID" exist

Comment: Can you run show create table of each table, thus we can recreate the schema?

Answer (score 0):

The issue reported is due to the fact that the `O` alias was introduced in a sub-query and thus cannot be used in an outer join.

Consider eliminating the sub-query, which also solves the initial problem.

```sql
SELECT ..
FROM Customers AS C 
JOIN Orders AS O ON C.customer_ID = O.customer_ID -- Join/alias here
LEFT JOIN Tour AS T ON C.trip_Taken = T.tour_ID 
LEFT JOIN Staff AS S ON O.staff_ID = S.staff_ID   -- So it can be used here    
LEFT JOIN Payment AS PA ON O.pay_ID = PA.pay_ID 
-- Promote sub-query conditions
-- (FWIW, the conditions look odd: a customer has only one "travel date"?)
WHERE NOT (C.travel_Date >= '2014-07-08 00:00:00' 
           AND C.travel_Date <= '2014-07-08 23:59:59')
```

The above query will act differently if a customer has *no* orders, which can be addressed by changing the JOIN to a LEFT JOIN depending upon intent.